# Managing git branches for multiple deployments?

Tags: git, azure, heroku, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I will be deploying my Django code in either AWS Elastic Beanstalk, Heroku, Google Cloud or Azure (we have not figured out which yet) and am currently testing all environments. For each environment, I will make changes to the settings.py file between the environments.

Since they all utilize git, I would maintain different branches based for each environment.

As the master branch progresses, how would I maintain the branch-specific changes to the settings.py file? Won't my environment-specific branch lag behind?

Or can I do a rebase? I'm confused how I would manage this.

Comment: Have you tried simply merging master into one/all of your environment branches?

Comment: Hey Lasse, that would not make sense, because the various settings.py files directly contradict each other.

Comment: Do you change settings.py in your branches all the time? Because if not you should just avoid merging that one file when you do. If you do a merge, ignoring the changes to that file that the merge would bring along, the next time you merge it will still ignore the same changes.

Comment: Have you considered *not* storing these files in source control? What about just making the configuration on the server itself and letting it be just there?

Answer (score 0):

Use one branch for all your deployments, but with a different (conditional) `settings.py` files suitable for each environment.

Take a look at [this](https://medium.com/@ayarshabeer/django-best-practice-settings-file-for-multiple-environments-6d71c6966ee2) example